# Changing a .net Framework dll requires re-signing?

Tags: c#, .net, gac

If we decompiled a .net framework dll (eg .System.Linq.Expressions.dll  ) present in GAC, made some changes in IL and assembled it back do we need to re-sign it ?

Comment: You cannot resign it you don't have the key. You also might find that any other framework ddls that depend on this one will stop loading.

Comment: @zespri ,I understand that ,but since the dll is already present in GAC , does it require resigning after i modify it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be able to add an assembly to the GAC you need to sign it with a strong name. And you will not be able to sign it as Microsoft because you do not have their private key. This means that the recompiled assembly gets a new strong name which is different from the strong name of the original assembly.

Comment: Since the dll is already present in GAC , does it require  resigning after i modify it ?

Comment: @AshleyJohn: When you (re)compile a DLL you will have to sign it before adding it to the GAC. **It is not possible to add an assembly to the GAC that does not have a strong name**. Because you will have to use your own key the assembly will get a strong name that is different from the original assemlys strong name. Basically, the GAC is tamper proof but with assembly redirection you may be able to redirect to your modified assembly.

Comment: So if i understand you correctly , even though the assembly already has a strong name and present in GAC, If I modify it then  i need to resign it with a new key to add it back to GAC . Right ?

Comment: @AshleyJohn: Yes, I am sort of repeating myself here, but to add an assembly to the GAC it has to have a strong name. For an assembly to have a strong name you need to sign it. If you try to "hack" the GAC by pulling out an assembly and recompile it you will have to sign it again before you can add it to the GAC. And you can only sign an assembly with your own key - not Microsofts - giving the recompiled assembly a new strong name. And if you try to be sneaky and simply replace the physical DLL in the GAC folder then .NET will notice that the new DLL has a wrong or invalid strong name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

One of the ideas behind signing an assembly is to prevent someone from tampering with it.

So, if you do change the assembly, it'll need to be re-signed.

Answer (score 2):

If you need that resulted assembly to have a strong name (and I assume you need) - then yes, you need to sign it.

If you need this for your own experiments - you can sign it with your own key and add binding redirect in your project to use "your" DLL.